Tag name for pseudoreplication is misspelt
I just noticed that pseudorepliction ought to be pseudoreplication. Can we create a tag with the correct spelling and make the misspelt one a synonym?

Yes, we can do that.

@kjetilbhalvorsen Great! I've made the new one, [tag:pseudoreplication]

Made synonyms & merged now!

Fixed by kjetil b halvorsen: the new tag is pseudoreplication and the old one is now a synonym of it.
